# ASUS Vivobook 15 Dull Yellow Screen

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

I don't know if this is a problem for a ASUS Laptop but it makes me anxious and worried about the performance of my laptop.

When I open my laptop after a proper shutdown, the screen works properly, it has a vibrant color. However, when I try to sleep or stand by the laptop and open it again for few minutes, the screen turns to be dull yellow.

How can I fix this issue? Does this issue has to do something with the settings of the display?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I already fix the problem regarding the screen of ASUS Vivobook 15 which turns into dull yellow when I open after a sleep or a standy by for few minutes.

SOLUTION (For Windows 10):
Display Settings → Advanced display settings → Display adapter properties for Display 1 → Properties → Driver → Update Driver

For those who have encountered the same problem, I hope this solution will help. Thank You.

Comment: please place a checkmark into your own Answer box to show you have solved the problem and it is fixed and works properly so others may know that it can be closed, etc. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the "ASUS Splendid Video Enhancement Technology" utility there are hotkeys for using it, you may have hit it by mistake. I have read where people just uninstall it, because it is useless, you find it in the uninstall area of windows, through the control panel.

You may want to look at this article at answers.microsoft (2018)

[ASUS Splendid missing ICM file in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/asus-splendid-missing-icm-file-in-windows-10/e9bd4f3c-7518-475d-81f8-80f6c035f563)

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I try to search for ASUS Splendid Video Enchantment Technology utility on my laptop, yet the utility is not installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same laptop...It can be solved by going to:-

1. search system configuration
2. Go to services
3. Untick asus optimization
4. and reboot

But it will also cause the backlight of keyboard to not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change display profile from intel command centre or amd . it worked on my asus vivobook 2020